# SyncML (sync or update?)

Tags: android, web-services, synchronization, syncml

I'm faced with another dilemma, with regards to synchronizing (or updating?) data across to the server, from a mobile device (using Android).

I've looked into SyncML as the standard for doing this, but my big concern is that we plan on `syncing` a large amount of data across (not just 1 record), and probably only doing it once, twice or at most 3 times a day, or maybe not even once a day - all dependant on certain circumstances.

The other thing - the device or server will still be able to function properly without having to sync across. The sync would just be an `update`, essentially.

From reading up on the SyncML specs, it applies more to syncing across small pieces of data, and at a very fast interval (ie. every 5-15 minutes, but I guess can be regulated by the user). At any rate, the synchronization process is more involved, and important for both the device and the server (more so the device, I guess).

Here's a quote from the documentation that got me thinking:

> 2.2.3 Data synchronization SyncML is oriented towards synchronization of
>   small independent records, as the
>   modied records are transmitted
>   entirely. This is adequate for address
>   entries, short messages and similar
>   data. On the primary target of SyncML,
>   mobile devices, most data is of this
>   type. The devices must be able to keep
>   track which of their records have been
>   changed. Each record is identied by a
>   unique ID, so con icts can be detected
>   quite simple. As the record ID's may
>   not be arbitrarily chosen but
>   automatically created, mapping between
>   server and client ID's is dened in
>   the protocol. Mapping is always
>   managed by the server. When the client
>   receives a new item from the server,
>   he can send a map update command to
>   tell the server what ID he assigned to
>   the item. Now the server uses the
>   client ID in all his messages.

So, I guess my question is whether we should continue to look into SyncML for this, or built an in-house solution - maybe something more tailored to delivering large pieces of data across, which can define it as well?

Comment: What kind of data will you synchronize? Is it record-oriented? Are records large? Are changes within records small? (SyncML works OK at long intervals, too.)

Comment: Yes, it's record oriented - could be 100s of records from various tables. Ideally they'd all be sent at once. There will rarely be changes in the records - these will mainly be new records being sent up, or retrieved from the server.

Comment: Did you find any alternative existing solution to SyncML?

Answer (score 0):

I'm faced with the problem too. I prefer `syncml` solution, mainly because it's more extensible.

The data tables we want to sync are indeterminate, `syncml` may be a better choice.